Displacement map Distortion
I am trying to create a mesh of a grip ready for 3D printing I wanted to create a displacement map however I have found that when applied, the displacement map only projects onto the curved side instead of the top and bottom of the model. The Displacement is using a UV map to project from in which I baked a texture using the materials emission.
The Top and bottom of my grips have these straight lines where the displacement map is curved.
also the texture is a bit spikey see below



Currently I am unsure if the issue is to do with normal, The uv mapping of the displacement. I have tried moving the Islands around the UV map however that has not seemed to solve it.
This is my first time using UV maps so I'm sure I could have messed up the UV mapping any help would be greatly appreciated
Blend files with packed image


Hello could you please share your file (don't forget to pack your image)?

Sorry about that just added the file now with packed image.

If you mean that the texture is stetched on the flat sides, it's normal, check the UVs, you need to unwrap again, but first you need to unpin the UVs (Alt P in the UV Editor)

@moonboots that seems to have fixed it thank you, after messing around with the UV I have acheived this result, there are still some areas that need to be adjusted but it already looks much better. Ill post the result in the answer

@moonboots advice seems to have fixed it thank you, after messing around with the UV I have achieved this result, there are still some areas that need to be adjusted but it already looks much better.


Hello, Ben .. glad it's working out! For this to constitute an answer (In Stack Exchange's way, that may be helpful to others reading the archive later,) rather than what is really just a comment, it would be good to make this post self-contained. I would suggest, when you're done, to embed 2 images: a 'before' and 'after' of your UV's. That would be enough, I'm sure.
